# Heart Rate Service not found in Nexus 5

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Service with UUID '0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb' and characteristic '00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'  Not found in Google Nexus 5 having  Android version 6.0.1. Same would be not found in Pixel XL

But the same can be found in Samsung Galaxy On5 Pro & Android version 6.0.1.

Is Heart Rate service is only for some specific devices ? Below is the code i am using to detect Heart Rate Service

```
@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        //broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);

        for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gatt.getServices()) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Service UUID Found: " + gattService.getUuid().toString());
            for (int k = 0; k < gattService.getCharacteristics().size(); k++) {
                Log.v(TAG, "CHARACTERISTIC____: " + gattService.getCharacteristics().get(k).getUuid());
                if (gattService.getCharacteristics().get(k).getUuid().equals(UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT)) {
                    flag = true;
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic heartRate = gattService.getCharacteristic(UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);
                    setCharacteristicNotification(heartRate, true);
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unable to find heart rate sevice");
                }
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            flag = false;
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        }

    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
    }
}
```

Please help me to detect Heart Rate Service and it's characteristics on Nexus 5 Device.

Comment: I don't know for sure but I think it's a service from the Samsung Health suite. ( Pre installed on Samsung devices ) Try installing the Samsung Health app on the Nexus 5 and try your code again.

Comment: @Nico Still the same.. Not working even after installing Samsung Health App